# Rails, getting flash to work on redirection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

my root_path is basically redirecting to the most popular story at this instant.

my root is handled by pages#home action, which just redirects the user away to story_path(id).

when a user access an unauthorized page, I redirect that user to the root_url with the message "access denied." However, this doesn't work because at root the user is again redirected.

Any way to fix this?

Comment: where you do the redirect (you have a redirect_to root_url) add `if flash.empty?` .If flash is not empty you won't be redirected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are redirecting and want to persist the flash for an extra request, you could do that using

```
flash.keep
```

More info can be found from the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash).

Comment: this saved me from ```flash[:alert] = flash[:alert] if flash[:alert]```

Answer (score 0):

@Alok, Reading the doc from the link you post also provides:

```
redirect_to root_url, :notice => "You have successfully logged out"
```